# Store the text value in a radio button in a decimal variable using Visual Studio 2012, c#

Tags: c#, .net, radio-button, decimal, radio-group

I currently have 3 radio buttons in 3 groups, and I just needed to pull the text value from the currently checked radio button in the each group and store it in the decimal value. 
Any ideas?

My current code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal loanAmount; 
        decimal interestRate;
        Int16 numberOfPayments;
        decimal monthlyPayment;

        // create the web service object
        ISULoanLeaseCalculatorService myCalcWS = new ISULoanLeaseCalculatorService();

        monthlyPayment = (decimal)myCalcWS.LoanMonthlyPayment(
        Convert.ToDouble(loanAmount),
        Convert.ToDouble(interestRate),
        Convert.ToDouble(numberOfPayments));

    }
}
```

Comment: A radio button has the value "on" or "off". I assume you mean the radiobutton's label text is a decimal value?

Comment: Use WPF, bind with a converter. We need more information to help much more. You haven't even specified what tech you are using (Winforms, WPF, ASP?)

Comment: Why do you need to store in a decimal Variable?
I prefer to save the radio buttons in a group to an enum.
Radion Button Group:
( ) A
( ) B
 => Enum:
enum enumName
{
A,
B
}

Comment: You should be able to delete your own questions, just click the "delete" button below the tags.

Comment: You can't delete a post with answers.

Comment: Use the "flag" link and ask a moderator to delete it. Please do not deface your question. But also consider why you think it needs to be deleted.

Comment: I did flag it already, I've been waiting for it to be deleted.

Comment: Then keep on waiting. Your current strategy is asking more for a ban.

Answer (score 1):

You can react to the [CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event whenever a button is clicked.

Then grab the text associated with the button from the [Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158234%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property and try to parse it:

```
decimal myDecimalValue;

bool success = decimal.TryParse(rb.Text, out myDecimalValue);
if (!success) ShowSomeErrorMessage();
```